# Can I use easy connect library with the Roving Network XV Wifi module?

Tags: mbed

I am trying to create a mqtt connection over WIFI using the mbed LPC 1768 dev board and the Roving Networks RN-XV wifi module. I can create a mqtt connection over ethernet using the HelloMQTT example. I have also created a wifi connect using the WiflyInterface. I would like to be able to create  the wifi connection using the easy-connect library or to make the WiflyInterface implement the NetworkInterface.

The current issue is that I cant add WiflyInterface to the mbed-os with getting a Socket redeclaration error.

```
Error: Invalid redeclaration of type name "Socket" (declared at <a href="#" onmousedown="mbed_doc_goto('/mqtt-wifiy//extras/mbed-os/mbed-os.lib/features/net/network-socket/Socket.h', '28'); return false;">/extras/mbed-os/mbed-os.lib/features/net/network-socket/Socket.h:28</a>) in "WiflyInterface/Socket/Socket.h", Line: 25, Col: 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that WiflyInterface's Socket class declaration conflicts with OS 5's Socket class declaration.

I believe WiflyInterface is an mbed OS 2 only library and cannot be added to mbed OS 5 (mbed-os.lib) which comes with its own networking libraries.

You can learn about OS 5's networking libraries here:

WiFiInterface:
https://os.mbed.com/docs/v5.9/reference/wi-fi.html

Network Socket: https://os.mbed.com/docs/v5.9/reference/network-socket.html